# org-mode, list and regular header and another list?

Tags: org-mode

I like a1 / a2 / a3 to be in the same indent level.

Should I use something other than `list` for this purpose?

```
* header

  - a1

    *** bb (it's a description for a1)
      content

      - a2
       - a22
      - a3
```

Comment: I do not think that Emacs will treat `*** bb (it's a ...` as a subheading of the `- a1` list.  I think Emacs will treat `*** bb (it's a ...` as a third-level subheading of `* header` with a *missing* second-level subheading of that initial header.  Let me suggest using a `+` sign for a main list heading and a `-` for a sub-list.  Sometimes, I even place the words of main list with a `+` sign in all capitals.  I personally do not indent at all -- i.e., I like flush left for everything -- the additional asterisks and change in colors is sufficient to meet my needs.

Comment: @lawlist The value of `org-heading-regexp` is `"^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(.*?\\)\\)?[  ]*$"`. I.e., the stars for the heading must start at the beginning of line.

Comment: You can indent/outdent manually, or you can enter new entries in the list with `M-RET` which effectively runs `org-insert-item` when you type it at the end of a list item. Once you are in a deeper level, I don't know of any slick way to outdent to a shallower level: I do it manually.